# Is it possible to send Emails with a different number of inline Images in Html Body each, using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

Good afternoon, I'm currently using the code below which allows me to add either 1 inline image or No inline images in the html body of a series of emails sent, grabbing the image ID from GDrive that is placed in specific spreadsheet cells in same column.
The script works correctly, but I would like to know whether, for the loop of emails to be sent (each row of the spreadsheet) could it be possible to grab a variable number of IDs, and in those cells with multiple Ids, these coming separated by a comma?
F.i.
First email IDs cell: Id1,Id2
Second email IDs cell: Id3,Id4,Id5,Id6
Third email IDs cell: (blank)
Fourth email IDs cell: Id7
and so on...

Thanks.

This is the my actual working code:

```
function sendEmails(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('SendMail')
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();

  var quotaLeft = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();
  //Logger.log(quotaLeft);

   if((lr-1) > quotaLeft) {
     Browser.msgBox("You have " + quotaLeft + " left and you're trying to send " + 
    (lr-1) + " emails. Emails were not send.");
   } else {

    for (var i = 2;i<=lr;i++){

  var currentEmail = ss.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
  var currentSubject = ss.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
  var templateText = ss.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
  var currentname = ss.getRange(i, 4).getValue();
  var reply = ss.getRange(i, 5).getValue();
  var imageFile = ss.getRange(i, 6).getValue();
  var image = ""
   Logger.log("Cell: " + ss.getRange(i, 6).getA1Notation());
   Logger.log("Image: "+ DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getRange(i, 6).getValue()));

    if(imageFile){
     try{
    image = DriveApp.getFileById(imageFile).getBlob();
      } catch (e) {
   templateText += "<p>Image merge failed: " + e;         
   }
  }

  var message = templateText.replace("{name}",currentname);
  message += "<br/><br/><img src=\"cid:sampleImage\">";

  if(image){
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: currentEmail,
    replyTo: reply,
    subject: currentSubject,
    htmlBody: message,
    inlineImages: {sampleImage: image},    
  });

    } else {

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: currentEmail,
    replyTo: reply,
    subject: currentSubject,
    htmlBody: message,  
  });
}

    } //close for loop

  } //close else statement

 } //close sendEmails
```

Comment: Do you mean that there are multiple picture IDs in 1 cell in CSV format? Please post a screenshot of an example range of cells.

Comment: precisely... some cells would come with comma separated Ids in case there would be more than one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the row of IDs and use a loop to build the HTML for the inline images

````
    function sendMail(){

      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('SendMail')
      var lr = ss.getLastRow();
      var lc = ss.getLastColumn();

      var quotaLeft = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();

       if((lr-1) > quotaLeft) {
         Browser.msgBox("You have " + quotaLeft + " left and you're trying to send " + 
        (lr-1) + " emails. Emails were not send.");
       } else {

        for (var i = 2;i<=lr;i++){

      var currentEmail = ss.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
      var currentSubject = ss.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
      var templateText = ss.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
      var currentname = ss.getRange(i, 4).getValue();
      var reply = ss.getRange(i, 5).getValue();
      var imageID = ss.getRange(i, 6, 1, lc).getValues().toString().split(',').filter(String);
      var image = {};

      var message = templateText.replace("{name}",currentname);


          for (var x = 0; x < imageID.length; x++){
            try{
          image["inlineImage"+x] = DriveApp.getFileById(imageID[x]).getBlob();   
          message += '<br/><img src="cid:' + "inlineImage"+x +'" />';
            } catch (e) {
                templateText += "<p>Image merge failed: " + e;         
           }
           }

      if(image){
      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: currentEmail,
        replyTo: reply,
        subject: currentSubject,
        htmlBody: message,
        inlineImages: image,    
      });

        } else {

      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: currentEmail,
        replyTo: reply,
        subject: currentSubject,
        htmlBody: message,  
      });
      }

        } //close for loop

      } //close else statement

     } //close sendEmails```
````

Comment: Simply Excellent!

Answer (score 1):

My reading of [MailApp.sendEmail(recipient,subject,body,options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)) suggests that you have to have this sort of html:

`<img src="cid:imagekey1" /><img src="cid:imagekey2" />`

for this sort of command:

`MailApp.sendEmail({currentEmail,currentSubject,non Html body (required),(replyTo:reply,htmlBody:"....<img src="cid:imagekey1" /><img src="cid:imagekey2" />...." ,inlineImages: {imagekey1:imgblob1,imagekey2:imgblob2}})`

These are the only advanced options in the documentation:

```
attachments BlobSource[]    an array of files to send with the email (see example)
bcc String  a comma-separated list of email addresses to BCC
cc  String  a comma-separated list of email addresses to CC
htmlBody    String  if set, devices capable of rendering HTML will use it instead of the required body argument; you can add an optional inlineImages field in HTML body if you have inlined images for your email
inlineImages    Object  a JavaScript object containing a mapping from image key (String) to image data (BlobSource); this assumes that the htmlBody parameter is used and contains references to these images in the format <img src="cid:imageKey" />`
```

NOTE: It says that the body argument is required.

`name   String  the name of the sender of the email (default: the user's name)
    noReply Boolean true if the email should be sent from a generic no-reply email address to discourage recipients from responding to emails; this option is only possible for G Suite accounts, not Gmail users
    replyTo String  an email address to use as the default reply-to address (default: the user's email address)`

And I don't see any `to:` option.

So I believe you will have to adjust your html programmatically with the number images you have to send.

Comment: Thanks @Cooper Does this solution allow me to have variable amount of inline images for each email sent or always the same amount?

Comment: I think it's upto you and whatever the max size of an email can be.